# Remove value from localstorage when leaving url in Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

Currently whenever I load onto page "x", I create a instance in local storage:
<TabList, { id: 1, action: 27 }>
This only happens when I load the page, but whenever I leave this page to go to a different page in the website, I want to destroy this exact instance of that key.

Page X: [image]

Service: [image]

The Goal: Whenever I leave this page, destroy the instance of "1, 27" from localstorage. I tried to do it on NgOnDestroy, but it's not working as intended.

Comment: Perhaps use a [route guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at some plain old JS window events, one that I've used successfully is "beforeunload"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => doTheThing());
```